Why map method returns .map is not a function?
The array
const props: NavButtonProps[] = [
    {
        text: "Home",
        url: "teste"
    },
    {
        text: "Services",
        url: "teste"
    },
    {
        text: "projects",
        url: "teste"
    }
]

where the method map is used
const NavButtonWrapper = (buttons: NavButtonProps[]): ReactElement => {
    return (
        <div className="flex space-x-16">
            { buttons.map((button) => { return (<NavButton {...button}/>)})}
        </div>
    )
}

I've already seen some cases where it works, but i don't know why in my code it returns buttons.map is not a function

Probably you need to declare interface NavButtonWrapperProps { buttons: NavButtonProps[]; } and then use it in your wrapper component.

Components always receive one parameter (props) which is always  an object. You are attempting to use buttons directly instead of accessing it through props.

try it this way:
    import React from 'react';

    interface NavButtonProps {
      text: string;
      url: string;
    }

    const App: React.FC = () => {

      const buttons: NavButtonProps[] = [
        {
          text: 'Home',
          url: 'test',
        },
        {
          text: 'Services',
          url: 'test',
        },
        {
          text: 'Projects',
          url: 'test',
        },
      ];

      // This is only for testing, you can replace it with your own component
      const NavButton: React.FC<NavButtonProps> = ({ text, url }) => {
        return (
          <li className="nav-button">
            <a href={url}>{text}</a>
          </li>
        );
      };

      const NavButtonWrapper: React.FC = () => {
        return (
          <div className="flex space-x-16">
            {buttons.map((button, index) => (
              <NavButton key={index} {...button} />
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <NavButtonWrapper />
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default App;


Destructure the props to access the buttons prop.
const NavButtonWrapper = ({ buttons } : { buttons: NavButtonProps[] }) => (
    <div className="flex space-x-16">
        {buttons.map(button => <NavButton {...button}/>)}
    </div>
);


It's just a syntax error, you can try removing () after return statement ,
Find the below code
{buttons.map((button) => {
return <NavButton {...button} />;

})}
Thanks, hope this help.

A syntax error causes .map is not a function?
